# VIM 9 Word boundary Change for Perl files

Tags: perl, vim, vim-perl

In vim 8, if you had the following string:

```
package Some::Package::Name;
```

and you placed your cursor on the `S` in `Some::Package::Name` and did a `cw` it would replace the text `Some` with whatever you typed.

In vim 9, `cw` now changes from `S` to the `e` in `Name`.

That behavior is probably due to a change in

```
/usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/perl.vim
```

Muscle memory is hard to change, and I would prefer if I could revert back to Vim8 behavior.  I've looked at the syntax file above and I am at a complete loss on how to change it.

Does anyone know how I can override this change in my vimrc?

My `.vimrc` remained unchanged between vim8 and vim9.  With the following perl relevant sections:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.pm set filetype=perl
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.t set filetype=perl
let g:ale_perl_perl_executable = '/opt/perl/bin/perl'
let g:ale_perl_perl_options = '-c -Mwarnings -Ilib -I/opt/perl/lib'
let b:ale_linters = { 'perl': [ 'perl' ] }
let g:ale_sign_column_always = 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the built-in syntax script has nothing to do with this.

It's the built-in filetype plugin:

```
$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/perl.vim
```

that adds `:` to `:help 'iskeyword'`, which is the option that tells Vim, among other things, where the next "word" start:

```
setlocal iskeyword+=:
```

In short, it tells Vim that `:` is part of the current word so `cw` skips it because it is not considered a separator anymore.

That setting was apparently added [9 years ago](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/543b7ef7000d08d77409478315d68b607bb8bad8#r14743673).

If you don't want it, you can create this file:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/perl.vim
```

with this content:

```
setlocal iskeyword-=:
```

which is sourced *after* the built-in filetype plugin and thus overrides whatever option you set in it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm one of the maintainers of the [vim-perl project](https://github.com/vim-perl/vim-perl), which is what feeds vim the syntax files.

You say

> If you placed your cursor on the S in Some::Package::Name and did a cw it would replace the text Some with whatever you typed.

> In vim 9, cw now changes from S to the e in Name.

I am not seeing that behavior that you describe for vim 9. I suspect that there may be something else that changed in vim 9 that is interfering with that.

I think a better place to figure out why that is would be to create an issue in the vim-perl project describing the problem, and we'll see what we can do to help you figure it out.

Comment: For future reference, the issue is https://github.com/vim-perl/vim-perl/issues/326